# Server crashing after sending a command?

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

My server crashes everytime i use the `create_graph` function and my regression tests all come back like this :

```
echo "+++ regress install-check in  +++" && /usr/local/pgsql-15/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../src/test/regress/pg_regress --inputdir=./ --bindir='/usr/local/pgsql-15/bin'    --load-extension=age --inputdir=.//regress --outputdir=.//regress --temp-instance=.//regress/instance --port=61958 --encoding=UTF-8 --dbname=contrib_regression scan graphid agtype catalog cypher expr cypher_create cypher_match cypher_unwind cypher_set cypher_remove cypher_delete cypher_with cypher_vle cypher_union cypher_call cypher_merge age_global_graph age_load index analyze graph_generation name_validation drop
+++ regress install-check in  +++
============== removing existing temp instance        ==============
============== creating temporary instance            ==============
============== initializing database system           ==============
============== starting postmaster                    ==============
running on port 61958 with PID 385940
============== creating database "contrib_regression" ==============
CREATE DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
============== installing age                         ==============
CREATE EXTENSION
============== running regression test queries        ==============
test scan                         ... FAILED (test process exited with exit code 2)      190 ms
test graphid                      ... FAILED (test process exited with exit code 2)       11 ms
test agtype                       ... FAILED (test process exited with exit code 2)        1 ms
test catalog                      ... FAILED (test process exited with exit code 2)        1 ms
test cypher                       ... FAILED (test process exited with exit code 2)        1 ms
test expr                         ... FAILED (test process exited with exit code 2)        1 ms
test cypher_create                ... FAILED (test process exited with exit code 2)      193 ms
test cypher_match                 ... FAILED (test process exited with exit code 2)       12 ms
test cypher_unwind                ... FAILED (test process exited with exit code 2)      199 ms
test cypher_set                   ... FAILED (test process exited with exit code 2)       11 ms
test cypher_remove                ... FAILED (test process exited with exit code 2)      192 ms
test cypher_delete                ... FAILED (test process exited with exit code 2)       11 ms
test cypher_with                  ... FAILED (test process exited with exit code 2)      194 ms
test cypher_vle                   ... FAILED (test process exited with exit code 2)       11 ms
test cypher_union                 ... FAILED (test process exited with exit code 2)      201 ms
test cypher_call                  ... FAILED (test process exited with exit code 2)       11 ms
test cypher_merge                 ... FAILED (test process exited with exit code 2)      199 ms
test age_global_graph             ... FAILED (test process exited with exit code 2)       11 ms
test age_load                     ... FAILED (test process exited with exit code 2)      213 ms
test index                        ... FAILED (test process exited with exit code 2)       10 ms
test analyze                      ... FAILED (test process exited with exit code 2)      201 ms
test graph_generation             ... FAILED (test process exited with exit code 2)       11 ms
test name_validation              ... FAILED (test process exited with exit code 2)      195 ms
test drop                         ... FAILED (test process exited with exit code 2)       11 ms
============== shutting down postmaster               ==============

========================
 24 of 24 tests failed. 
========================

The differences that caused some tests to fail can be viewed in the
file "/home/panos/Documents/age-fork/regress/regression.diffs".  A copy of the test summary that you see
above is saved in the file "/home/panos/Documents/age-fork/regress/regression.out".
```

also here is what happens when the server crashes

```
postgres=# select * from create_graph('test_graph');
TRAP: FailedAssertion("ptr == NULL || nodeTag(ptr) == type", File: "../../../src/include/nodes/nodes.h", Line: 609, PID: 380560)
postgres: panos postgres [local] SELECT(ExceptionalCondition+0xa5)[0x55ebdb81f1f2]
postgres: panos postgres [local] SELECT(+0x2a8d0b)[0x55ebdb4aed0b]
postgres: panos postgres [local] SELECT(DefineSequence+0xa1)[0x55ebdb4b0622]
postgres: panos postgres [local] SELECT(+0x4d285d)[0x55ebdb6d885d]
postgres: panos postgres [local] SELECT(standard_ProcessUtility+0xa90)[0x55ebdb6d784b]
/usr/local/pgsql-15/lib/age.so(ag_ProcessUtility_hook+0xba)[0x7f1e1c1029d4]
postgres: panos postgres [local] SELECT(ProcessUtility+0x44)[0x55ebdb6d789d]
postgres: panos postgres [local] SELECT(CreateSchemaCommand+0x3d6)[0x55ebdb4ad1c9]
/usr/local/pgsql-15/lib/age.so(+0x1882a)[0x7f1e1c10382a]
/usr/local/pgsql-15/lib/age.so(create_graph+0x43)[0x7f1e1c103c7a]
postgres: panos postgres [local] SELECT(ExecMakeTableFunctionResult+0x22b)[0x55ebdb516e04]
postgres: panos postgres [local] SELECT(+0x325090)[0x55ebdb52b090]
postgres: panos postgres [local] SELECT(+0x3118b3)[0x55ebdb5178b3]
postgres: panos postgres [local] SELECT(ExecScan+0x7c)[0x55ebdb51794d]
postgres: panos postgres [local] SELECT(+0x324f9c)[0x55ebdb52af9c]
postgres: panos postgres [local] SELECT(+0x30e486)[0x55ebdb514486]
postgres: panos postgres [local] SELECT(+0x30677b)[0x55ebdb50c77b]
postgres: panos postgres [local] SELECT(standard_ExecutorRun+0x15a)[0x55ebdb50c954]
postgres: panos postgres [local] SELECT(ExecutorRun+0x23)[0x55ebdb50ca1e]
postgres: panos postgres [local] SELECT(+0x4cd9cc)[0x55ebdb6d39cc]
postgres: panos postgres [local] SELECT(PortalRun+0x34b)[0x55ebdb6d54cd]
postgres: panos postgres [local] SELECT(+0x4cb337)[0x55ebdb6d1337]
postgres: panos postgres [local] SELECT(PostgresMain+0x73f)[0x55ebdb6d32c3]
postgres: panos postgres [local] SELECT(+0x424a46)[0x55ebdb62aa46]
postgres: panos postgres [local] SELECT(+0x427b98)[0x55ebdb62db98]
postgres: panos postgres [local] SELECT(+0x427dd3)[0x55ebdb62ddd3]
postgres: panos postgres [local] SELECT(PostmasterMain+0x1141)[0x55ebdb62f38c]
postgres: panos postgres [local] SELECT(main+0x226)[0x55ebdb56f86a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x29d90)[0x7f1e25e29d90]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x80)[0x7f1e25e29e40]
postgres: panos postgres [local] SELECT(_start+0x25)[0x55ebdb2cf0c5]
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: 2023-05-26 00:22:23.365 EEST [380530] LOG:  server process (PID 380560) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
2023-05-26 00:22:23.365 EEST [380530] DETAIL:  Failed process was running: select * from create_graph('test_graph');
2023-05-26 00:22:23.365 EEST [380530] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2023-05-26 00:22:23.365 EEST [380694] FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
Failed.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.
!?> 2023-05-26 00:22:23.365 EEST [380530] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2023-05-26 00:22:23.372 EEST [380695] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2023-05-26 00:22:08 EEST
2023-05-26 00:22:23.454 EEST [380695] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2023-05-26 00:22:23.457 EEST [380695] LOG:  redo starts at 0/1616418
2023-05-26 00:22:23.457 EEST [380695] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/1616450: wanted 24, got 0
2023-05-26 00:22:23.457 EEST [380695] LOG:  redo done at 0/1616418 system usage: CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s
2023-05-26 00:22:23.462 EEST [380696] LOG:  checkpoint starting: end-of-recovery immediate wait
2023-05-26 00:22:23.471 EEST [380696] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.004 s, sync=0.002 s, total=0.011 s; sync files=2, longest=0.001 s, average=0.001 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=0 kB
2023-05-26 00:22:23.475 EEST [380530] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Im using Postgres 15.3 and im currently developing the apache AGE to be compatible with verison 15. Everything was going smoothly when suddenly without changing anything this happened. Also I reverted any possible changes and this kept happening when it should't have because i have already run a lot of tests for like 10 hours.

Comment: Looks like a bug in your code. What more can I say from here?

Comment: The weird thing is the server was fine until it just didn't, and after i reverted the changes it still wasn't fine which is odd because if it was a bug in my code, reverting all the changes i made should have fixed that right?

Comment: Did you `git clean -fxd` and build from scratch?

Comment: yup exactly that command. I even uninstalled postgres and re installed it

Comment: Try locating the regression.diffs file and see why the tests are failing.

Comment: The tests say that they cant connect to the server, they drop the connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What could be the cause for problem is that you mistakenly corrupted some of files or you have a storage problem, so check first you have enough storage (which sometimes turns out to be the cause for a lot of problems that come out of nowhere), if it's not the problem, then what could be helpful in your case is to recompile postgres once and recompile the age as well by `make install` for both, but make sure you `make clean` before that. I hope that solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

*TRAP: FailedAssertion* is telling that there is some problem with your AGE version.
The server is crashing maybe due to:

- Your installed AGE have some bugs in it.
- Compatibility problems between your postgres and AGE version.

Answer (score 0):

Check compatibility of AGE with PostgreSQL. If both are compatible you can check the `regression.diff` file. There are two directories named `expected` and `result` which has all the test case files. You can compare the crashing files results from these two directories and hopefully you will be able to check why your server is crashing.